# asp.net Ado stored procedure fields

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have the following select in an stored procedure:

```
Select I.ID,
           I.Name,
           I.NameUrl,
           I.Teaser,
           I.Description,
           I.Coords,
           I.Banned,
           I.DateAdded,
           I.TypeID,
           I.MainCategoryID,
           C.Name,
           C.NameUrl,
           C.Description
from Items I
inner join Categories C on C.ID=I.MainCategoryID
```

Some of the columns in few tables have the same name.

The asp.net ADO code below doesnt work for this equal names that im using.

My question is: Do i have to give a name, in the sql query, to the fields C.Name, C.NameUrl and C.Description in order to get it from the datatable indicated below? I Mean, i would like to avoid to put (in every stored procedure) the "C.Name as CategoryName", "C.ID as CategoryID", etc... Do you know a solution?

```
item.Name = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["Name"]);
item.NameUrl = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["NameUrl"]);
item.Teaser = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["Teaser"]);
item.Description = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["Description"]);
item.DateAdded = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["DateAdded"]);
item.IsBanned = Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[0]["Banned"]);
item.MainCategory = new Category();
item.MainCategory.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["MainCategoryID"]);
item.MainCategory.Name = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["C.Name"]);
item.MainCategory.NameUrl= Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["C.NameUrl"]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Jose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the column name from the result set without the qualifier.

However, you have ambiguous column names. So you need to alias them:

```
Select I.ID,
           I.Name AS ItemName,
           I.NameUrl AS ItemNameUrl,
           I.Teaser,
           I.Description AS ItemNDescription,
           I.Coords,
           I.Banned,
           I.DateAdded,
           I.TypeID,
           I.MainCategoryID,
           C.Name AS CategoryName,
           C.NameUrl AS CategoryNameUrl,
           C.Description AS CategoryDescription
from Items I
inner join Categories C on C.ID=I.MainCategoryID
```

and

```
item.Name = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["ItemName"]);
item.NameUrl = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["ItemNameUrl"]);
item.Teaser = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["Teaser"]);
item.Description = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["ItemDescription"]);
item.DateAdded = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["DateAdded"]);
item.IsBanned = Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[0]["Banned"]);
item.MainCategory = new Category();
item.MainCategory.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["MainCategoryID"]);
item.MainCategory.Name = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["C.CategoryName"]);
item.MainCategory.NameUrl= Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["C.CategoryNameUrl"]);
item.MainCategory.Description= Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["C.CategoryDescription"]);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to refactor your database to use the right column names. Without refactoring your database, you will have to refactor your stored procedures to correctly identify the columns.

Either way, you are in for quite a bit of typing.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you do aliasing, otherwise it will always give problem

```
Select I.ID,
       I.Name as IName,
       I.NameUrl,
       I.Teaser,
       I.Description as Idescription,
       I.Coords,
       I.Banned,
       I.DateAdded,
       I.TypeID,
       I.MainCategoryID,
       C.Name as CName,
       C.NameUrl,
       C.Description as Cdescription from Items I
 inner join Categories C on C.ID=I.MainCategoryID
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably use an alias for the same naming column like

```
 Select I.ID,
I.Name as itemname,
I.NameUrl as itemurl,
I.Teaser,
I.Description as itemdesc,
I.Coords,
I.Banned,
I.DateAdded,
I.TypeID,
I.MainCategoryID,
C.Name as catname,
C.NameUrl as caturl,
C.Description as catdesc 
from Items I inner join Categories C on C.ID=I.MainCategoryI
```

Answer (score 0):

As a few others have said, you'll need to alias the names in your Stored Procedure and they have given you examples on how to do so.  Alternatively, you can SELECT INTO a temp table and name them what you would like and then have your code pull from the temp table without any aliasing needed on the code-side. However, there is no getting around having to alias the stored procedure. Good Luck!